# How to bind BigDecimal value to Currency in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, bigdecimal

Hi I am using jquery autoNumeric to format my input values in currency format. I want to bind these formatted values to BigDecimal in SpringPortlet. Please let me know how I can do it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spring 3+ or 4+ you should use format annotations. For example (from the spring docs):

```
@NumberFormat(style=Style.CURRENCY)
private BigDecimal decimal;
```

In the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch05s06.html), section 5.6.2, there is a full description on how to enable this. I'm currently doing exactly this with the jquery autoNumeric lib and it seems to work without problems for me.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this but I get a easy work around by implementing the below webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")), false));

Comment: That solution is good only if *all* BigDecimal instances are used for US currencies. The app I'm building uses BigDecimal for currency, but also for other values, such as percentages.